# .Net async sockets seems does not queue packages

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asyncsocket

First, sorry for my english.
I have a problem with my .net async sockets.

I have a server and 60 clients that send packages constantly. The problem came when the clients send packages at same time (more than 7 packages).

I think that the server Receive func is not queue the packages correctly.

My code:

```
private void RecibirPaquetes(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        //recibo el paquete del cliente y lo registro en su socket
        Socket socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        if (!socket.Connected)
            return;

        int cant_recibido;

        cant_recibido = socket.EndReceive(ar);


        //si el paquete contiene algo, lo proceso
        byte[] paqueteRecibido = new byte[cant_recibido];
        Array.Copy(this.buffer, paqueteRecibido, cant_recibido);

        //deserializo el paquete
        var paquete = paqueteRecibido.Deserializar();

        //proceso el paquete y tomo todas las decisiones correspondientes
        this.ProcesarPaquete(paquete as PaqueteCliente, socket);

        socket.BeginReceive(this.buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(this.RecibirPaquetes), socket);

        this.cantPaquetesRecibidos += 1;
        this.bytesRecibidos += cant_recibido;
    }
```

I try to change the buffer size but does not resolve my problem. I cant understand why this is happening.
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by packages, but to be clear - TCP's abstraction is a *stream of bytes*. If you want "messages", it's up to you to implement message framing (by e.g. sending fixed size messages, prefixing with the length, etc). TCP Sockets will just give you as many bytes as are currently available. In other words, there's no 1-1 correspondence between calls to `Send` at one side and calls to `Receive` at the other.

Comment: TCP is a stream-based protocol. You will receive data in exactly the order it's sent, but you can *not* assume that packet boundaries are respected. So for starters, your receive logic is wrong: you are assuming one call to `.EndReceive` will give you all the data for one request, which need not be true. `.EndReceive` can give you back any number of bytes (except 0, which happens when the connection is closed). This is irrespective of how many bytes the remote site actually sent you in one packet. This is a classic error because code like this tends to work by coincidence on localhost.

Comment: The main problem is that when I send data to the clients, not all receive the same. So I think that could be this I've told you or the send method could be too.

Comment: If your clients use the same faulty logic, assuming that packet boundaries are respected, they'll experience the same issues with received data apparently not matching up with what is sent. Another possible issue is that if you issue multiple asynchronous calls on the same socket, the order in which they're actually processed is undefined. Typically, however, all connections use their own socket and you don't send more than one thing at a time, so that's not a common issue.